# Predicting random numbers based on past output

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I've been working on a program to predict random numbers based on previous digits. However, I only get access to numbers from 0-53 inclusive, and one only comes every 30 seconds or so, therefore gathering hundreds or thousands of sequential data points is nigh impossible. I also don't know the algorithm being used, although right now I am assuming it is the Mersenne Twister.

With all that being said, here is the code that I am using:

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import time
start = time.time()

data = [5, 49, 9, 2, 8]
datalength = len(data)


def actual():
    for i in range(9999999999):
        l1 = []
        random.seed(i)
        append = l1.append

        for i2 in range(datalength):
            x = random.randrange(0, 54)

            try:
                if data[x] == i2:
                    append(x)
            except IndexError:
                break

def next_100(x):
    l1 = []
    random.seed(x)
    for i in range(datalength):
        x = random.randrange(0, 54)
    for i in range(100):
        l1.append(random.randrange(0, 54))
    return l1

with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    result = pool.apply_async(actual).get()

z = next_100(result)
print('The next 100 should be: {0}'.format(z))
print('It took {0} seconds'.format(round(time.time()-start)))
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a better algorithm than I am currently using? (that works with my limited knowledge)
2. If not, how else can I optimize this? Right now, I can't really guess more than 100 million seeds in a reasonable amount of time. Seed 100 million takes ~23 minutes, and 1 billion should take about 230 minutes, which is way more time than I have.

Comment: ýour algorithm is trying to solve an impossible problem. A Mersenne Twister can be seeded with 2^64 different values, and no matter how fast your program is, you will not be able to check any significant fraction of them.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but aren't there only 4.2 billion possible values? My data is based on this (https://www.bishopfox.com/blog/2014/08/untwisting-mersenne-twister-killed-prng/) link, although there is a real chance I am misinterpreting something.

Comment: oh, it depends whether it is seeded with a 32 or 64 bit int. If it's 32 bit, you have a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find or create a Mersenne Twister [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). In other words, pre-compute all (or some subset) possible outputs, store them (time-space tradeoff), and compare the series you receive to the stored series.

The article quoted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618836/how-if-at-all-does-a-predictable-random-number-generator-get-more-secure-after suggests the number of values you need to store may be much smaller.